# USB Serial port programming has "disastrous" results

Tags: linux, usb

I am currently working on a C program running on a Raspberry Pi 3 (Linux Ubuntu) that is intended to provide a web page interface for configuring networking on an embedded system.

The code is being developed using Code::Blocks with the GDB debugger.  I'm using microhttpd for the web server and that, plus the various web pages, are all working great.  I'm now working on the USB Serial link to the embedded system using information in "Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems".

The code below is responsible for opening the USB Serial link to the target system and seems to work fine - once.  If I close the program and restart it (either standalone on the command line or from within Code::Blocks) the second time microhttpd is hosed - browser windows will no longer connect.  Further, from within Code::Blocks the debugger is also hosed - once the program is started it cannot be paused or stopped.  The only way is to kill it by closing the project.

The problem is clearly within the function since I can comment out the call to it and everything works as it did previously.  Unfortunately, once the problem happens the only solution seems to be to reboot the Pi.

I've done things like this before using a scripting language (Tcl) but this time around I'm looking for a performance boost from a non-interpreted language since the Pi will also be running a high bandwidth data logging program through a similar USB serial interface.

The code is shown below:

```
/******************************************************************************/
/* This function scans through the list of USB Serial ports and tries to      */
/* establish communication with the target system.                            */
/******************************************************************************/

void tapCommInit(void) {
    char line[128];
    char port[15];   // this is always of the form "/dev/TTYACMn"
    char *ptr; 
    FILE *ifd;
    struct termios options;
    uint8_t msgOut[3], msgIn[4];

    msgOut[0] = REQ_ID;                       // now prepare the message to send
    msgOut[1] = 0;                                  // no data so length is zero
    msgOut[2] = 0;


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* First, get the list of USB Serial ports.                               */
    /**************************************************************************/

    system("ls -l /dev/serial/by-path > usbSerial\n");  // get current port list
    ifd = fopen("usbSerial", "r");
    logIt(fprintf(lfd, "serial ports: \n"));


    /**************************************************************************/
    /* The main loop iterates through the file looking for lines containing   */
    /* "tty" which should be a valid USB Serial port.  The port is configured */
    /* in raw mode as 8N1 and an ID request command is sent, which has no     */
    /* data.  If a response is received it's checked to see if the returned   */
    /* ID is a match.  If not, the port is closed and we keep looking.  If a  */
    /* match is found, tapState is set to "UP" and the function returns.  If  */
    /* no match is found, tapState is left in the initial "DOWN" state.       */
    /**************************************************************************/

    while(1) {
        if (fgets(line, 127, ifd) == NULL) {                     // end of file?
            break;                                 // yes - break out and return
        }
        ptr = strstr(line, "tty");  // make sure the line contains a valid entry
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            continue;                         // nothing to process on this line
        }
        strcpy(port, "/dev/");                      // create a correct pathname 
        strcat(port, ptr);              // append the "ttyACMn" part of the line
        port[strlen(port)-1] = 0; // the last character is a newline - remove it
        logIt(fprintf(lfd,"  %s\n", port));     // we have a port to process now
        cfd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);   // cfd is a global int
        if (cfd == -1) {
            logIt(fprintf(lfd, "Could not open port: %s\n", port));
            continue;                   // keep going with the next one (if any)
        }
        fcntl(cfd, F_SETFL, 0);                                 // blocking mode
        tcgetattr(cfd, &options);               // get the current port settings
        options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); // ena receiver, ignore modem lines
        options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);      // raw, no echo
        options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;               // no special output processing
        options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;         // minimum number of raw read characters
        options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;   // timeout in deciseconds (1 second timeout)
        tcsetattr(cfd, TCSANOW, &options);              // set options right now
        cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);                       // input baud rate
        cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);                      // output baud rate
        options.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB |      // clear size bits, no parity
          CSTOPB | CRTSCTS);                   // 1 stop bit, no hw flow control
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;                // now set size: 8-bit characters
        options.c_cflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);        // no sw flow control

        if (write(cfd, msgOut, 3) < 3) {
            logIt(fprintf(lfd, "Sending of output message failed\n"));
            close(cfd);
            continue; 
        }
        if (read(cfd, msgIn, 4) != 4) {
            logIt(fprintf(lfd, "Didn't get expected amount of return data\n"));
            close(cfd);
            continue; 
        }
        if (msgIn[3] != HOST_ID) {
            logIt(fprintf(lfd, "Got the wrong HOST_ID response\n"));
            close(cfd);
            continue; 
        }
        logIt(fprintf(lfd, "Port found - communication established\n"));
        tapState = UP;
        break;                             // we're done - break out of the loop
    }
    fclose(ifd);                         // close and remove the file we created
    remove("usbSerial");
}
```

Comment: This program of yours...it connects to the web server how? CGI? FastCGI? And if that link is not relevant, then why is it relevant that a web server is involved at all?

Comment: The libmicrohttpd package is a C library that uses a pool of threads, one per connection, and uses callbacks in another part of my program to serve out the web page information.  The only relevancy is the fact that something I'm doing in the above function seems to be killing libmicrohttpd operation.  This is pretty much my first involvement with C under Linux - I'm more of an embedded hardware guy - so I'm currently at a loss as to how to approach solving this problem.

Comment: Global variables (i.e. `cfd`) and threads don't mix. You're setting yourself up for a race condition or worse here. Besides which, [threads are evil](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf). I think you might be better off writing this in Go, Node, or in fact anything else that raises the abstraction level above threads.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but you might want to do `popen` instead of `system` and `fopen`.  Better yet, `open("/dev/serial/by-path",  …)` and call `readdir`.

Comment: @Scott: You will find that my answer already recommends that.

Comment: One out of two ain't bad.   :-)   So, to be clear, you're feel no shame in the fact that you're recommending that the OP keep on parsing the output of `ls`?

Comment: @Scott: I'm a Perl programmer, so of course not. :) But seriously, you're right, a [`readdir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) loop would be less wasteful. My lack of shame here is more a reflection of the fact that the resulting speed increase would not affect the running time of this program in the least, because shortly after it called `closedir()`, it would be sitting there twiddling its thumbs waiting most of a hundred microseconds, blocked on the serial port `read()`. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from within Code::Blocks the debugger is also hosed - once the program is started it cannot be paused or stopped

It is far more likely that you do not understand your tools than that you have created an unkillable program.

It's easy enough to figure this out: divide and conquer. You've got a whole pile of unrelated components here. Start separating them and find out which pieces work fine in isolation and which continue to behave badly when disconnected from everything else. Then you'll have your culprit.

Specifically here, that means try running your program outside the IDE, then under command line `gdb` instead of GDB via the IDE.

Also, it should be possible to run your program without starting the web server piece, so that you can run the serial part of the app in isolation. This is not only good for debugging by minimizing confounding variables, it also encourages a loosely-coupled program design, which is a good thing in its own right.

In the end, you may find that the thing keeping your program from stopping is the web framework, Code::Blocks, or the way GDB operates on the Pi under Code::Blocks, rather than anything to do with the USB to serial adapter.

> once the problem happens the only solution seems to be to reboot the Pi

If your program is still running in the background, then of course your next instance will fail if it tries to open the same USB port.

Don't guess, find out:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep ttyACM
```

or:

```
$ lsof -p $(pidof myprogram)
```

(Substitute `pgrep` if your system doesn't have `pidof`.)

> I've done things like this before using a scripting language (Tcl) but this time around I'm looking for a performance boost from a non-interpreted language

Your serial port is running at 115,200 bps. Divide that by 10 to account for the stop and start bits, then flip the fraction to get seconds per byte, and you come to 87 microseconds per byte. And you only achieve that when the serial port is running flat-out, sending or receiving 11,500 bytes per second. Wanna take a guess at how many lines of code Tcl can interpret in 87 microseconds? Tcl isn't super-fast, but 87 microseconds is an eternity even in Tcl land.

Then on the other side of the connection, you have HTTP and a [W]LAN, likely adding another hundred milliseconds or so of delay per transaction.

Your need for speed is an illusion.

Now come back and talk to me again when you need to talk to 100 of these asynchronously, and then *maybe* we can start to justify C over Tcl.

(And I say this as one whose day job involves maintaining a large C++ program that does a lot of serial and network I/O.)

Now lets get to the many problems with this code:

> ```
> system("ls -l /dev/serial/by-path > usbSerial\n");  // get current port list
> ifd = fopen("usbSerial", "r");
> ```

Don't use a temporary where a pipe will suffice; use [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) here instead.

> ```
> while(1) {
> ```

This is simply wrong. Say `while (!feof(ifd)) {` here, else you will attempt to read past the end of the file.

This, plus the next error, is likely the key to your major symptoms.

> ```
> if (fgets(line, 127, ifd) == NULL) { 
>     break;
> ```

There are several problems here:

1. You're assuming things about the meaning of the return value that do not follow from the documentation. [The Linux `fopen(3)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) isn't super clear on this; the [BSD version](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) is better:

   > The fgets() and gets() functions do not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

   Because `fgets()` is Standard C, and not Linux- or BSD-specific, it is generally safe to consult other systems' manual pages. Even better, consult a good generic C reference, such as [Harbison & Steele](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X). (I found that much more useful than K&R back when I was doing more pure C than C++.)

   Bottom line, simply checking for `NULL` doesn't tell you everything you need to know here.
2. Secondarily, the hard-coded `127` constant is a code bomb waiting to go off, should you ever shrink the size of the `line` buffer. Say `sizeof(line)` here.

   (No, not `sizeof(line) - 1`: `fgets()` leaves space for the trailing null character when reading. Again, RTFM carefully.)
3. The `break` is also a problem, but we'll have to get further down in the code to see why.

Moving on:

> ```
> strcat(port, ptr);              // append the "ttyACMn" part of the line
> ```

Two problems here:

1. You're blindly assuming that `strlen(ptr) <= sizeof(port) - 6`. Use [`strncat(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncat/) instead.

   (The prior line's `strcpy()` (as opposed to `strncpy()`) is justifiable because you're copying a string literal, so you can see that you're not overrunning the buffer, but you should get into the habit of pretending that the old C string functions that don't check lengths don't even exist. Some compilers will actually issue warnings when you use them, if you crank the warning level up.)

   Or, better, give up on C strings, and start using [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). I can see that you're trying to stick to C, but there really are things in C++ that are worth using, even if you mostly use C. C++'s automatic memory management facilities (not just `string`, but also `auto_ptr`/`unique_ptr` and more) fall into this category.

   Plus, C++ strings operate more like Tcl strings, so you'll probably be more comfortable with them.
2. Factual assertions in comments must *always* be true, or they are likely mislead you later, potentially hazardously so. Your particular USB to serial adapter may use `/dev/ttyACMx`, but not all do. There's another common [USB device class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_classes) used by some serial-to-USB adapters that causes them to show up under Linux as `ttyUSBx`. More generally, a future change may change the device name in some other way; you might port to BSD, for example, and now your USB to serial device is called `/dev/cu.usbserial`, blowing your 15-byte `port` buffer. *Don't assume.*

   Even with the BSD case aside, your `port` buffer should not be smaller than your `line` buffer, since you are concatenating the latter onto the former. At minimum, `sizeof(port)` should be `sizeof(line) + strlen("/dev/")`, just in case. If that seems excessive, it is only because 128 bytes for the line buffer is unnecessarily large. (Not that I'm trying to twist your arm to change it. RAM is cheap; programmer debugging time is expensive.)

Next:

> ```
> fcntl(cfd, F_SETFL, 0);                                 // blocking mode
> ```

File handles are blocking by default in Unix. You have to *ask* for a nonblocking file handle. Anyway, blasting all the flags is bad style; you don't know what *other* flags you're changing here. Proper style is to get, modify, then set, much like the way you're doing with `tcsetattr()`:

```
int flags;
fcntl(cfd, F_GETFL, &flags);
flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(cfd, F_SETFL, flags);
```

Well, you're *kind of* using `tcsetattr()` correctly:

> ```
> tcsetattr(cfd, TCSANOW, &options);
> ```

...followed by further modifications to `options` without a second call to `tcsetattr()`. Oops!

You weren't under the impression that modifications to the `options` structure affect the serial port immediately, were you?

> ```
> if (write(cfd, msgOut, 3) < 3) {
>     logIt(fprintf(lfd, "Sending of output message failed\n"));
>     close(cfd);
>     continue; 
> }
> ```

Piles of wrong here:

1. You're collapsing the short-write and error cases. Handle them separately:

   ```
   int bytes = write(cfd, msgOut, 3);
   if (bytes == 0) {
       // can't happen with USB, but you may later change to a
       // serial-to-Ethernet bridge (e.g. Digi One SP), and then
       // it *can* happen under TCP.
       //
       // complain, close, etc.
   }
   else if (bytes < 0) {
       // plain failure case; could collapse this with the == 0 case
       // close, etc
   }
   else if (bytes < 3) {
       // short write case
   }
   else {
       // success case
   }
   ```
2. You aren't logging `errno` or its string equivalent, so when (!) you get an error, you won't know *which* error:

   ```
   logIt(fprintf(lfd, "Sending of output message failed: %s (code %d)\n",
              strerror(errno), errno));
   ```

   Modify to taste. Just realize that `write(2)`, like most other Unix system calls, has a whole bunch of possible error codes. You probably don't want to handle all of them the same way. (e.g. `EINTR`)
3. After closing the FD, you're leaving it set to a valid FD value, so that on EOF after reading one line, you leave the function with a valid but closed FD value! (This is the problem with `break` above: it can implicitly return a closed FD to its caller.) Say `cfd = -1` after every `close(cfd)` call.

Everything written above about `write()` also applies to the following `read()` call, but also:

> ```
> if (read(cfd, msgIn, 4) != 4) {
> ```

There's nothing in POSIX that tells you that if the serial device sends 4 bytes that you will get all 4 bytes in a single `read()`, even with a blocking FD. You are especially unlikely to get more than one byte per `read()` with slow serial ports, simply because your program is lightning fast compared to the serial port. You need to call `read()` in a loop here, exiting only on error or completion.

And just in case it isn't obvious:

> ```
> remove("usbSerial");
> ```

You don't need that if you switch to `popen()` above. Don't scatter temporary working files around the file system where a pipe will do.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a very lengthy response - it will probably take most of the day to go through it and completely understand it (I'm fairly new at all this).  A couple of quick points though - in digging around on the web I had already discovered "sudo lsof | grep /dev/ttyACM" but when I ran it (after a fail), it produced no output at all.  As for why I'm doing this in C over Tcl - two reasons.  First, I don't know how much system load the data logger will present and second, It's a learning experience.  I want to learn more about things I can do in C under Linux.

Comment: Done, but I don't have enough "reputation" yet for it to be counted.  Obligatory quote: "Doing things right comes from experience.  Experience comes from doing things wrong".  As you can see from the above code, I'm clearly in the experience gathering mode right now.

Comment: @DavidHarper: Re experience, don't discount any of the criticisms above. It may seem harsh, but I've got a couple of decades writing programs of this sort. Every critique above has a battle scar backing it.

Comment: @DavidHarper: Re the load from adding the data logger, the worst case is that you divide the byte time by half, so your program ends up wasting at least *43* microseconds per byte waiting on the next byte. Still an eternity in software, even in Tcl. And if by "logging" you mean that the data will be going to persistent storage, you can't make the micro SD card on the Pi run faster by writing to it from C than when writing to it from Tcl. The bottom line is that your problem is wholly [I/O-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound), not [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound).

Comment: The criticisms above don't bother me in the least - I've already learned a lot from your post and the various comments.  Part of my problem is I'm self-taught in C and Unix (which were still about 10 years in the future when I was in school).  While learning, I tended to track down the knowledge I needed to put out the current fire as quickly as possible before moving on to the next fire.  Thus, there's a "few" gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: The data logger will be a completely separate program running on the Pi.  The incoming logging data will be written to an external USB drive and data rates could be as high as 50KB/sec although current rates are less than 10KB/sec.  A Tcl version of that program has been running for about six months now in support of the embedded hardware design which is where the data originates.